# Computer freezes, no errors, just everything dysfunctional

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

My Sony Vaio laptop will freeze with the following symptoms:

After a few minutes (usually from 2 to 60 minutes of working), the whole screen freezes.

Mouse or keyboard won't work.

There is no activity on the HDD usage light on the laptop.

The fan will constantly work at a definitive level (not speeding up or down)

The only way to make the computer work will be to hold down the power button and then start it up once again.

What can cause such a problem? I can't revert to the last update because the 10 days have passed and I can't just reset the PC because there is so much on my laptop.

Thanks

Comment: Check for hard disk SMART errors and also temperature overload.

Comment: Does it work when you start in safe mode?

Comment: See if you have hardware errors. Get the Sony Hardware Diagnostic App (Sony support site) and scan all your hardware for errors.

Comment: Ensure the air vents are clean and that the air vents aren't blocked during usage.  As far as "I can't just reset the PC because there is so much on my laptop.", the data must not be important or else you'd have a back up of it.

Comment: I reinstalled the Windows OS and everything seems to be working for now; however, I believe temperatures were resulting in such a confusing problem.